# How do I add both event and root to callback in python tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating a basic application using tkinter and I want to split the code for my gui and my code for functions and stuff into different files, but this function:

```
from tkinter import *
from functions import * # this is my file I want to put my functions in

# FUNCTIONS that needs root and event
def callback(event): # my question is about this function
    root.after(50, select_all, event.widget)

# Setup
root = Tk()
```

(bind)

```
edtLocation1 = Entry(root)
edtLocation1.bind('<Control-a>', callback)
```

Needs to take in an event and root at the same time if I move it to a new file, but I cannot do this inside another file:

```
def callback(event, root): # gives error because I have to pass in an event
        root.after(50, select_all, event.widget)
```

Since I don't know how to pass in an event...

Long question short, how could I go about passing an event and root into the callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lambda:

```
def callback(event, root):
    root.after(50, select_all, event.widget)

...

edtLocation1.bind('<Control-a>', lambda e: callback(e, root))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass in root. You can call the `after` method from any widget, and the `event` object that is passed in has a reference to the widget that caught the event.

```
def callback(event):
    event.widget.after(50, select_all)
```